# How to create migration on pivot table to delete on cascade

Tags: php, laravel

The many to many relationship works. The original working migration:

```
Schema::table('tag_topic', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('topic_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned()->index(); 
});
```

I want the pivot table items to be deleted when referenced items are deleted. The new migration:

```
Schema::table('tag_topic', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->foreign('topic_id')->references('id')->on('topics') ->onDelete('cascade');
   $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

The pivot table row items are not cascaded deleted.

Update:

I dropped the table and rewrote the the migration, but still the pivot rows are not cascade deleted:

```
    Schema::create('tag_topic', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('topic_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned(); 
        $table->foreign('topic_id')->references('id')->on('topics')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

This code deletes the pivot table rows:

```
$tag = Tag::where('id', $tag->id)->get()->first();
$Tag->topics()->detach();
```

Comment: try to add `$table->engine = 'InnoDB';` before `$table->foreign('topic_id')->references('id')->on('topics') ->onDelete('cascade');` !!

Comment: @Maraboc it didn't work

Comment: Make sure you add it to all migrations or it would not work. !!

Comment: there are 2 migrations: the one creating the table and the one for onCascade delete. I roll back the latest one, add the line and re-migrate. But how to add it to the first migration? I also migrated to the 2 referenced tables

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping your old indexes before applying the foreign key constraints.

```
Schema::table('tag_topic', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropIndex(['topic_id']);
    $table->dropIndex(['tag_id']);

    $table->foreign('topic_id')->references('id')->on('topics')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Comment: it's not working. Does the down function need to be defined in order to rollback?

Comment: To rollback per se you need a down function, but to drop the foreign key as per the above code, you should be able to just add the code to a new migration timestamped after the original migration you're referencing.